# How to fix inoperative autofocus in Canon 70-200 F4 L USM?

Tags: lens, canon, autofocus, troubleshooting, repair

This lens has been sitting on the shelf for years and I recently hauled out my DSLR to play with it. Turns out the autofocus no longer works. I'm wondering if there's any kind of remedy for this short of sending it back to Canon? I may want to sell the lens as a $300 repair + shipping is as much as the lens is worth.

I've tried gently scrubbing the contacts with a microfiber cloth.

I don't think the lens has been dropped. Holding out hope for some kind of remedy.

Comment: I would try another body with the same lens. This may also be a duplicate question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-lens-autofocus?rq=1

Comment: Also try switching the AF/MF switch back and forth a few times, and make sure it's firmly on 'AF'

Comment: I've tried it on a couple bodies now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be as firmly on AF as I can make it.

Comment: Also, the shutter won't release in AF (because it can't focus). It will in manual. So it seems to be communicating the mode switch.

Comment: Doing a little checking: a used 70-200 F4 L in decent condition can be had for around $600. While it's certainly *possible* that a repair would be $300, it probably won't be that much. Not sure about your options, but my local shop has some kind of deal with Canon where they ship it to Canon, get an estimate, and I can then decide whether I want to go ahead with it. If I decide not to, all I pay is the shipping (usually around $35). If I do, it's just the cost of the repair. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: try using a pencil eraser on the contacts...may have light corrosion that a cloth won't remove. Worth a shot anyway

Comment: Do you want to sell it? If you would be willing to, email me

Comment: When you put it in auto focus and turn the focus ring, is it stiff? If so, does it make any noise? If you don't hear the motor turning, it could mean a bad motor drive.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is send it back to the Canon Service Center. It won't cost that much if it's only a focusing problem. I had them fix a 50mm F1.2L and change the lens barrel for around $120, service charge included. This lens cannot focus and the lens barrel rubber is loose. They changed the focusing gears and the barrel, as may be the same problem as your lens, and it didn't cost that much.

It's never a good idea to mess around with such products as it may do more damage than good.

Comment: I would disagree with the "**never** a good idea" bit. I have successfully fixed a number of lenses, both for myself and for some friends. However, I do electrical engineering with a side of mechanical engineering professionally, so I have some familiarity with fixing things. As with most topics, it's really a matter of what you're comfortable with.

Comment: @FakeName : I would really welcome your advice on fixing a Canon 200mm 1.8 prime lens. The autofocus (and manual focus...) do not work at all...

Comment: @SkippyFastol - Whooo boy, I don't know if I'd feel comfortable taking a $6K lens apart. Anyways, the fact that manual focus doesn't work is actually a good thing. It means the issue with the lens is mechanical, rather then electronic. (Assuming this lens has full-time-manual-focus (I'm pretty sure it does)). Does the lens communicate with a camera properly, and does the iris work?

Comment: There are a few images showing partial disassembly of that lens here: http://www.pbase.com/bigflat/ef_200mm_f18l_disassembly . It is intended for showing how to clean the internal elements of the lens, but it includes removing the focusing cell, which it likely the part of the lens that is stuck in some manner (The problem is *probably* in the helicoid). How does the focusing-ring feel? Does it feel stuck, or does it feel like it's no longer connected to anything?

Comment: @FakeName: seems the focusing technique of that lens is called "focus by wire" : http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/746628

Comment: @FakeName: also, when I read this : http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/technical/usmlens_technology.do , I can't see how a USM motor could even break...

Comment: @Fake Name : thanks so much for your feedback. - I'd say the issue is electronic don't you think ? Doesn't this lens have a purely electronic drive even for manual focus ? The iris works perfectly :).

Thanks you so much for the disassembly link.

The focusing reel feels very smooth. As you say, no longer connected to anything :) By the way, my question was posted there : Tools and spare parts needed to repair Canon 200mm f1:1.8 USM prime lens

Comment: If it's focus-by-wire, the problem is almost certainly in the electronics. This is unfortunate, as the electronics are much less repairable. I think your best bet would be to disassemble the lens, and check for loose connections. If you don't find any (it's a pretty unlikely failure mode), I think your only hope is to send it to canon, and let them fix it.